# GoogleMap.setpadding() is undefined for the type GoogleMap

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using Eclipse and some methods do not appear to be available for GoogleMaps objects.

I have imported the google-play-services_lib, made sure I had the latest versions of Google Play Services and I am running the latest API (Version 4.4.2 (API 19). I removed all of them as well and re-installed them.  The Map Fragment works great on my test device. However when I try to implement methods such as .setPadding() I get an error that .setpadding is undefined for the GoogleMap object.

It should be in here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding(int, int, int, int)

Any ideas?

public class MapDemo extends Activity implements LocationListener {

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapdemo);


    try {
        initilizeMap();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void initilizeMap() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
    // map.
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();


        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setPadding(0,0,30,0); // **<--This method does not appear to be in the API!**


        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (googleMap != null) {
            // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.

              options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
              .compassEnabled(false) .rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
              .tiltGesturesEnabled(false) ;




        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the most recent version of the Google Play Services library project? According to the Maps API changelog, the `setPadding()` method was added in [September 2013](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#september_2013).

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem.  The google-play-services_lib that I had imported was imported from a copy I had manually downloaded instead of the google-play-services_lib that is maintained and updated by the Android SDK Manager. Now, magically, I have the new methods!